# How do I root my Samsung Galaxy S3?

Tags: rooting

I downloaded Titanium Backup to my Android Samsung GS3, but I got a message saying I must root my phone for the software to work. How do I root my phone?

Comment: Which one is it: [Galaxy S3 i9300](/a/26880/16575) // [i9305](/q/89370/1465) // [Galaxy S3 Duos3](/q/110169/1465) // [Galaxy S3 Lite](/q/91808/1465) (S6790) // [Galaxy S3 Mini GT-i8190](/q/47805/1465)? Find those (and many more) on our [rooting index](/q/1184/16575) ;)

Answer (score 0):

Download king root from aptoide! This should do the job ! If you dont know what aptoide is! Download the apk from aptoide website! You also have to enable in the security option allow install from unknown source!

Comment: Wow! Everything here seems almost Explosive! Superlative! and Happy!

Comment: Have you tried king root on all S3 variants? Happy with the side effects? Your phrasing ("should do the job") suggests you have not. So please don't throw in untested stuff as answer. Can be dangerous. Same for Aptoide, if you don't know how to deal with it (only the "Apps" repository is curated). So what you suggest means double-danger.

Comment: Yer i did test kingroot , on most of the phone it works really well. I have rooted many phone with it!  but your right using aptoide is tricky and you must be carefull, that said .. google play store can be as armfull ! Most people dont know! Next time ill gather more information on the device in question and post a more accurate answer! tank you for saying this to me! This only preves to me that this site is quite reliable and we are among people we can trust! Greatly appreciated! But keep im mind i would not say or recommend to someone anything i havent tried or dont know about!